# How to manage an Android app privately and outside the Android Market?

Tags: android, enterprise

I'm currently building an app for a client who wants to manage the apk afterwards, without publishing it on the Android market. He wants to provide the app to a limited number of users.

- To do so, I've first thought making a second app that will manage the updates of the first one.
- Then I thought it was a bit complicated and I found [Pushlink](https://www.push-link.com/). This is exactly what I need except one part of the terms and conditions that I fear :

> 1.1 PushLink reserves the right to update and change the Terms of Service from time to time without notice.

I've got actually two questions :

- Does anyone of you have experience using Pushlink, how supported is it?
- Is there any alternative to Pushlink?

Many thanks.

Romain

Comment: Have you thought about implementing your own update service where your app reaches out to a server.. checks a version code there.. if its a new version it will download it and attempt to install it. ?

Comment: I've thought of that solution but I'm not sure how to manage the update from the app itself. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, in my app I have a plain text file sitting on my server that just has a version number in it. I check that value against the actual value in APK file installed. If its higher I download the new APK to the SD card. Once the download finishes you create an intent to install the app. [See the answer to this question on how to create that intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically). It's fairly easy to do, actually.

Comment: it sounds good, add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: FWIW, I have a work-in-progress JAR for adding self-update logic to an app: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to your proposed solution would be to implement your own internal updating logic.

I've done this myself and it's very simple to maintain.

- Have a plain text file on a server that can be accessed from your application.

  - This file will contain the most up to date version number.
- Every so often (maybe once or twice a week) check the server to see if the version numbers differ (Server # > In app #).
- Download your new APK from the server onto the SD card.
- Once you finish downloading the file you'll need to launch an intent to install the application. The user will still have to accept to install the update so its not %100 autonomous but you prevent the user from doing anything aside from clicking "Install".

  - [Check the answer to this question regarding the install intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I use http://auto-update-apk.com - it is really simple but it does what it's supposed to, and it's free for small apps.